# Is this proof of dim(row(A))=dim(col(A)) correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

My teacher skipped the proof saying that it is a little difficult, but I made a proof and found it to be simple, so I doubt if there is a mistake in this proof.

$RREF$=Reduced row echleon form. Pivot=the first non-zero terms in each non-zero row in $RREF$ of any matrix. Pivotal columns = columns which contain the pivot in $RREF$. LS = linear span. $A(-;i)=ith$ column of a matrix.

$A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix. Let $R=RREF(A)$.

Non-pivotal columns of $R$ can be represented as a linear combination of pivotal columns of $R$ (details skipped).

So, $LS$(pivotal columns of $R$)$=$$col(R)$.

Also, the pivotal columns of $R$ are clearly linearly independent. So, $dim(col(R))=$number of pivotal columns in $R=rank(R)$.

Now, $\sum_{k=1}^{r}c_kR(-;i_k)=0\Rightarrow c_k=0, k=1,2,3,...,r.$, where $i_k$ are the positions of pivotal columns of R. But $\sum_{k=1}^{r}c_kR(-;i_k)=0\Leftrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{r}c_kA(-;i_k)=0,$ since we can multiply by the invertible matrix $P$ and $P^{-1}$ on left side, where $A=PR$ (details skipped).

So, $\sum_{k=1}^{r}c_kA(-;i_k)=0\Leftrightarrow c_k=0, k=1,2,3,...,r.$.

So the columns at $i_{k}^{th}$ positions of $A$ are linearly independent.

Also, multiplying by $P$ on both sides of $R(-;j)=\sum_{k=1}^{r}c_kR(-;i_k)$, $A(-;j)=\sum_{k=1}^{r}c_kA(-;i_k)$.

So $col(A)$=$LS$(pivotal columns of $A$).

So the pivotal columns of $A$ form a basis of $col(A)$, and thus $dim(col(A))=rank(A)$, but $rank(A)=dim(row(A))$[we had already proved this in class and proof is simple], so $dim(row(A))=dim(col(A))$.

Comment: Your solution is full of jargony terminology and notation which needs to be explained, otherwise it makes little sense: *pivotal*; $RREF$; etc.

Comment: @LeeMosher These are standard terms I think, but I have included the meaning of some. Is it fine now?

Comment: Yes, better. The expanded acronyms are standard. The acronyms themselves are not.

Comment: @LeeMosher Using RREF for reduced row echelon form is pretty common, arguably "standard". I agree with you on the rest.

Comment: @failure Yes, your proof is essentially correct. It is also roughly equivalent to the [first proof presented here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Proofs_that_column_rank_=_row_rank).

Answer (score 1):

If we are allowed to use the inner product, we can come up with much simpler explanation.

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix and $A^t$ denote its transpose. We can treat $A$ as a linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m.$ Then the range of the mapping $A$ is equal the linear span of the columns. Therefore $\dim{\rm Im}\,A=\dim {\rm col} (A).$ The mapping $A$ restricted to $(\ker A)^\perp={\rm Im} A^t$ is injective and maps ${\rm Im} A^t$ onto ${\rm Im} A.$ Therefore  $\dim{\rm Im} A^t=\dim{\rm Im} A=\dim {\rm col} (A).$  But $\dim{\rm Im}\,A^t=\dim {\rm col} (A^t)=\dim {\rm row} (A).$